# CodeIgniter views, HTML, JS, and CSS compressing build tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter, build

Is there any open source or somewhat modifiable build tools to compress and minimize javascript and css files, and also CodeIgniter PHP view files?

Are there any tools that would compress id and class names used in HTML, CSS, and Javascript code? Similar to when you compress Javascript, you get a one letter variables.

As the final result, I'm looking to get something like the source of google.com.

Answer (score 1):

I use the build script of the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) on my view files and enable the `preserve-php` function

Answer (score 1):

this isn't the full answer but it should get you half way there.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Carabiner

"it will combine, minify, and cache assets."
i've used it and works quite sweetly.

regarding the view check out this post
http://www.herusetiawan.com/2010/12/minify-or-compress-html-output-with-codeigniter/
you can probably tweak it to do things like minify class/id names

Answer (score 0):

If you want a modern approach then using webpack is the way forward. It's an in depth topic I have a full series on it here in detail: http://mstd.eu/index.php/2017/03/02/using-webpack-in-codeigniter-3-step-1-set-up/

In short, you create your webpack.config.js file with all the commands you wish the build script to run and then in your package.json file you reference webpack in your scripts array so you can simply call npm run watch and it will compile on every change.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch"
  },
```

Comment: url is down, can you post it again?